# Interrupts using i2c and Python

Tags: python, c, interrupt, i2c

Some background:

I have an i2c device (MCP23017), which has 6 switches connected to its GPIO ports. The MCP23017 is connected to a Raspberry Pi via i2c.

I'm able to read the state of each of the switches as required.

My issue is in regards to interrupts. I'm using the WiringPi2 library for Python, which allows me to interface with the MCP23017 under Python. From the research I've done, the WiringPiISR library allows for i2c interrupt protocols to be run, although it only seems to work (properly) under C.

My question is this: is there a simple solution for implementing i2c interrupts under Python?

I'm considering dropping Python for C for this particular project, but the GUI interface has already been written (in Python), so I'd like to keep that as a last option.

Any guidance/input/comments would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If you've written your GUI in a reasonable way, there's no reason a Python GUI can't drive a C engine almost as easily as a Python engine, is there?

Comment: I have no idea? I've always used the same language for logic and GUI control. Is a Python GUI and C engine a potential solution I should look into?

Comment: It definitely can be. If you're using any kind of design with a decoupled GUI and engine (e.g., MVC), you can put any kind of shim you want in between—write the engine as a .so and talk to it over `ctypes`, or as a command-line program that you `subprocess` and talk to over stdio, or as a socket server that you either `subprocess` or run as a daemon and talk to over a socket, etc. Obviously that adds a bit of complexity to your design, but if you're right that i2c only works properly from C, and you don't want to write a GUI in C (which is rarely fun…), it might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @abarnert, it's much appreciated as always. I will endeavour to find an i2c solution for Python, knowing that I can always look at a Python/C GUI/engine mix if needs be.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can help, but… it sounds like this may be a library-shopping question. Are you asking how to fit i2c interrupts into Python's signal model so you can improve WiringPi2, or some other specific question like that, or are you asking for recommendations for a library that you can use to replace WiringPi2? Because if it's the latter, that doesn't fit on StackOverflow; it might fit on [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but a mailing list or forum or other venue that invites discussion might be a better bet.

Comment: What I'm really asking is how can I have a signal/slot system, like there is in PySide, using a change in i2c pin status as the signal, which triggers a predetermined function to be run. I suppose it is more suited to SoftwareRecs, I just thought I'd ask here first in case there was an obvious solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, WiringPiISR library only allows you to configure a Pin to be an interrupt and define its type (ie, edge based or level based). Since you're talking about I2c interrupt, there is no way you can have I2C interrupt as in this case, Your Rpi works as a master device and other connected device(s) as slave(s). Since in I2C, communication is always initiated by the master, slaves can not interrupt you. (at least not via I2C channel)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for information. It would appear that interrupts aren't something I can achieve with i2c on the RPi, so I'll have to look at other ways to achieve what I'm after. Thanks again!

Comment: Interrupt from MCP23017 or the MCP32008, can only be used with an Micro-Controller. The Raspberry Pi being a computer, it has no real time feature

Answer (score 0):

There are devices that have an interrupt line in addition to I2C lines. For example I have a rotary encoder I2C interface board from duppa.net which has 5 pins - SDA, SCL, +, - and interrupt.

The python library that comes with it configures the Raspberry Pi GPIO 4 line as an input edge triggered interrupt and sets up callbacks. On a change (the rotary encoder is rotated for instance) the interrupt line wiggles, the interrupt handler reads the status register over I2C and calls the appropriate callback.

So this is completely conventional interrupt usage in the context of I2C doing to usual task of freeing the master from having to poll the bus.